# BizTalk PromotePropertySchema does not appear in the Filter of SendPort

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009

I created a Promoted Property schema and tried to enter the property in the Filter of SendPort. But the Promoted Property does not appear in the list of Properties under Filters.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the setting for Property Schema Base is still the default, which is MessageDataPropertyBase.  These do not show up on filters or in the Orchestration Designer.

Change it to MessageContextPropertyBase and redeploy.

Comment: I am sorry Johns I am new to BizTalk, I dont find any Base Property in the PropertySchema.

Comment: It's a Property of the Property Element, not the Schema.

Select your custom Property, then look on the Property Page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct to say that MessageDataPropertyBase context properties are not available for filters. Both promoted properties are available for filter. The difference is in the source of values of these promoted properties.

With regard to why they are not available, make sure property schema is deployed Or if its deployed to another application, add a reference of it to application in which you are creating send port